# Convert Integer to UTF-8 Character?

Tags: vb.net, utf-8, integer, converters

I am trying to convert an integer to a UTF-8 character in VB.net. I have tried:

```
Function ConvertToUTF8(Input as Integer)
    Return Chr(Input).ToString
End Function

Function ConvertToUTF8(Input as Integer)
    Return Convert.ToUInt16(Input).ToString
End Function
```

But all I get are errors (First one) and numbers (Second one). I'm sure that there is an easy way to accomplish this that I am missing. I have looked on MSDN, but I could not find much :(

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried `Return Chr(Input)`?

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.strings.chr.aspx

You should also be able to do this:

`Return Convert.ToChar(Input)`

Comment: Valid Unicode code points for rendering into UTF-8 range from 0x000000 through 0x10FFFF, but necessarily exclude the UTF-16 surrogates as these cannot be legally encoded in UTF-8.